# Pandas Ordered Histogram Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, group-by, scikit-learn

So I have some data as such:

```
Epoch        Object User
1418409833   1      1
1418409834   1      2
1418409835   1234   1
1418409836   1234   1
1418409836   1589   2
1418409837   9      1
1418409838   9      2
```

How do I transform this frame to a numpy matrix of such:

```
[ 1 2 0 1
  1 0 1 1]
```

Where each row is a user and each column is a histogram bin value.
So in this case user 1 has 2 counts of object 1234, so the second index is 2.

Note though, here user 2 does not have object 1234 and thus needs a 0 in that corresponding column.

Use case is for scikit-learn classifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `groupby` to group by User, `value_counts` to compute a histogram, and `unstack` to reshape the result:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
        Epoch  Object  User
0  1418409833       1     1
1  1418409834       1     2
2  1418409835    1234     1
3  1418409836    1234     1
4  1418409836    1589     2
5  1418409837       9     1
6  1418409838       9     2

In [14]: df.groupby(['User'])['Object'].value_counts().unstack(level=1).fillna(0)
Out[14]: 
      1     9     1234  1589
User                        
1        1     1     2     0
2        1     1     0     1
```

You could then access the `values` attribute to obtain a NumPy array:

```
In [15]: df.groupby(['User'])['Object'].value_counts().unstack(level=1).fillna(0).values
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.]])
```